# How to display three bootstrap cards next to each other in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-5

For a personal project involving Java and React, I am trying to display movie data in bootstrap cards. The issue I have is that the cards are rendered vertically. What I am trying to achieve is having them rendered horizontally in rows of 3.

I have tried using different styling settings such as "display: inline-block", but none of them worked.

If anyone knows how I can fix my issue it would be a great help!

Here is my code:

**Moviespage.js**

```js
function Moviespage() {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    loadMovies();
  }, []);

  const loadMovies = () => {
    MovieAPI.getMovies()
      .then((res) => {
        setMovies(res.data.movies);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

  const getMoviesByTitle = (title) => {
    MovieAPI.getMoviesByTitle(`${title}`)
      .then((res) => {
        setMovies(res.data.movies);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

  const handleSearchChange = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setTitle(event.target.value);
    getMoviesByTitle(title);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Bootstrap.Container>
        <Bootstrap.Form.Control
          style={{ margin: "1% 0 0 0" }}
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search"
          value={title}
          onChange={handleSearchChange}
        />
      </Bootstrap.Container>
      <MovieCardList movies={movies} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Moviespage;
```

**MovieCardList.js**

```js
function MovieCardList(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.movies.map((movie) => (
        <MovieCard key={movie.id} movies={movie}></MovieCard>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default MovieCardList;
```

**MovieCard.js**

```js
function MovieCard(props) {
  return (
    <Bootstrap.Container>
      <Bootstrap.Row>
        <Bootstrap.Col className="col-sm-4">
          <Bootstrap.Card
            className="card-style"
            style={{ margin: "3% 0 0 0" }}
            key={props.movies.id}
          >
            <Bootstrap.Card.Body>
              <Bootstrap.Image src={props.movies.thumbnail} width={"100%"} />
              <Bootstrap.Card.Title>{props.movies.title}</Bootstrap.Card.Title>
              <Bootstrap.Card.Text>
                {props.movies.releaseYear}
              </Bootstrap.Card.Text>
              <Bootstrap.Card.Text>{props.movies.rating}</Bootstrap.Card.Text>
              <Bootstrap.Card.Text>{props.movies.genre}</Bootstrap.Card.Text>
            </Bootstrap.Card.Body>
          </Bootstrap.Card>
        </Bootstrap.Col>
      </Bootstrap.Row>
    </Bootstrap.Container>
  );
}

export default MovieCard;
```

Edit:

Thanks everyone for the help.

I managed to fix it by removing the ***Bootstrap.Container*** and ***Bootstrap.Row*** from **MovieCard.js** and adding ***Bootstrap.Row*** to **MovieCardList.js**

MovieCard.js

```
    return (
        <Bootstrap.Col className="col-sm-4">
            <Bootstrap.Card style={{ margin: "3% 0 0 0", borderColor:"#bbbbbb"}} key={props.movies.id}>
                <Bootstrap.Card.Body>
                    <Bootstrap.Image src={props.movies.thumbnail} style={{ width: "100%", height: `calc(1.75 * 322px)`, }} />
                    <Bootstrap.Card.Title>{props.movies.title}</Bootstrap.Card.Title>
                    <Bootstrap.Card.Text>{props.movies.releaseYear}</Bootstrap.Card.Text>
                    <Bootstrap.Card.Text>{props.movies.rating}</Bootstrap.Card.Text>
                    <Bootstrap.Card.Text>{props.movies.genre}</Bootstrap.Card.Text>
                    <Bootstrap.Card.Text>{props.movies.id}</Bootstrap.Card.Text>
                    {
                        localStorage.getItem("user-info").includes('ADMIN') && (
                            <Bootstrap.Button style={{ backgroundColor: "red", borderColor: "gray" }}
                                onClick={handleSubmit}><RiDeleteBin5Fill style={{ backgroundColor: "red" }} /></Bootstrap.Button>
                        )
                    }
                </Bootstrap.Card.Body>
            </Bootstrap.Card>
        </Bootstrap.Col>
    )
}
```

MovieCardList.js

```
    return (
        <div>
            <Bootstrap.Row>
                {
                    props.movies.map(movie =>
                        <MovieCard key={movie.id} movies={movie}></MovieCard>
                    )
                }
            </Bootstrap.Row>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: You can wrap a  grid in your card, 1 row with 2 columns. The first column is for the Card image and the second column is for the Card Body. Bootstrap utilities may be needed for further adjustments

Comment: Hi Funkops. The Boostrap grid system will not work because for each movie you are creating a <Container> and a <Row>. I suggest you to take out the <Container> and the <Row> from the map() loop call back, and just left the <Col> for <Card> content. With this its should work.

Answer (score 0):

in your `MovieCardList` add inline style of `display: flex`.

```js
function MovieCardList(props) {
  return (
    <div style="display: flex">
      {props.movies.map((movie) => (
        <MovieCard key={movie.id} movies={movie}></MovieCard>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default MovieCardList;
```

or `display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(3, fr);`

```js
function MovieCardList(props) {
  return (
    <div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(3, fr);">
      {props.movies.map((movie) => (
        <MovieCard key={movie.id} movies={movie}></MovieCard>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default MovieCardList;
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `className="container"` in your `MovieCardList`like so, should work.

```js
function MovieCardList(props) {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      {props.movies.map((movie) => (
        <MovieCard key={movie.id} movies={movie}></MovieCard>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default MovieCardList;
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row
}
```